# How to generate doc from a go program in go1.13

Tags: go

Here is a little program toto.go

```
// Copyright Some Company Corp.
// All Rights Reserved
package main


// here are the imports
import (
    "fmt"
)

// function to say hello
func hello() {
    fmt.Println("hello world")

}

// Main function here
func main() {
    hello()
}
```

How to generate an html documentation from this code ?

Result :

```
godoc -html  github.com/bussiere/GoTestDoc 
flag provided but not defined: -html
usage: godoc -http=localhost:6060
  -analysis string
        comma-separated list of analyses to perform (supported: type, pointer). See http://golang.org/lib/godoc/analysis/help.html
  -goroot string
        Go root directory (default "/usr/lib/go-1.13")
  -http string
        HTTP service address (default "localhost:6060")
  -index
        enable search index
  -index_files string
        glob pattern specifying index files; if not empty, the index is read from these files in sorted order
  -index_interval duration
        interval of indexing; 0 for default (5m), negative to only index once at startup
  -index_throttle float
        index throttle value; 0.0 = no time allocated, 1.0 = full throttle (default 0.75)
  -links
        link identifiers to their declarations (default true)
  -maxresults int
        maximum number of full text search results shown (default 10000)
  -notes string
        regular expression matching note markers to show (default "BUG")
  -play
        enable playground
  -templates string
        load templates/JS/CSS from disk in this directory
  -timestamps
        show timestamps with directory listings
  -url string
        print HTML for named URL
  -v    verbose mode
  -write_index
        write index to a file; the file name must be specified with -index_files
  -zip string
        zip file providing the file system to serve; disabled if empty
```

So it seems lot of things have changed since last time.
And it seems hard to find tutorial and doc up to date to make doc for golang in go1.13

Answer (score 2):

This is something you might be looking for

```
godoc -html <package-name>
```

You can refer to [this link](https://blog.golang.org/godoc-documenting-go-code) for more details

Answer (score 0):

1. Move your package folder under `GOPATH` directory.

```
$GOPATH/src/github.com/username/my-package
```

2. Use `godoc` to generate documentation for go project.

   - To generate html doc

```
godoc -html  github.com/username/my-package
```

- Alternate option:

```
godoc -http=:6060
```

Now you can visit `http://localhost:6060/pkg/github.com/username/my-package` to browse the documentation of your package.